# android aidl cannot bind to service, when host is installed after the client

Tags: android, android-service, ipc, aidl

I have an aidl service which works correctly till the client is installed when the host is installed before, but as I mentioned in the title when the host isn't installed and I install the client and after that I install the host I get a SecurityException on **bindService()**

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(AidlService.class.getName());
if (!mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(serviceIntent, 0).isEmpty()) {
    mContext.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { act=com.mypackage.AidlService}
```

i have also tested a few application that use aidl and they had the same problem !

**UPDATE**

I figured out that the problem is with permission,
as my service uses a custom permission when the client is installed before the host it can't understand the permission, so when I install the host and try to bind to it, android can't use the permission, so it throws a security exception !

```
android:permission="com.mypackage.AidlService.BIND"

<permission android:name="com.mypackage.AidlService.BIND"
            android:label="@string/perName"
            android:description="@string/perDesc"
            android:protectionLevel="normal" />
```

any idea to fix the problem ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007139/not-allowed-to-bind-to-service-intent

Comment: good question, I was stuck with this too. couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Android Custom Permission Fails Based on App Install Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730085/android-custom-permission-fails-based-on-app-install-order)

you should use android:protectionLevel="signature" instead of normal
in permission tag

Comment: thnx a lot saved me weeks of search