# Secure communication between two peer apps with/without custom permissions

Tags: android, security, android-permissions

In my project, I am developing 3 components:

1. An accessory for smartphone
2. A **controller app** for this accessory
3. An **API** allowing 3rd party apps to bind to the software controller to use the accessory

Items 2 and 3 must communicate between them securely, this is why I use the system of custom permissions. The controller app defines the permission `com.myproject.CONNECT` that 3rd party apps must hold to use the accessory.

Manifest of the software controller:

```
<permission android:name="com.myproject.CONNECT" />
...
<service
    android:name="com.myproject.services.ControllerService"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.myproject.CONNECT" >
</service>
```

Manifest of the 3rd party apps using my API and binding to my service:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.myproject.CONNECT" />
```

BUT, this system requires the controller app to be **always installed before** any 3rd party app, otherwise the latter will get a `SecurityException` as if it didn't have the permission (as pointed out in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730085/android-custom-permission-fails-based-on-app-install-order)).

This is definitely not an option in my case as the controller app and the 3rd party apps are peers (completely independent, same importance). A common trick, as presented [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/PERMS.md#the-peer-apps-case-part-one-a-then-b), is to have both apps (controller and 3rd party) *define* the same `<permission>`. But this behaviour is **no longer supported in the Android L developer preview** as two apps doing this must have been signed by the same key, which is not possible here.

Do you think there's a working solution based on the custom permission system... Otherwise how could I secure the communication and make sure that the bindings come from my API and not any malware?

Thank you very much!

Comment: "Items 2 and 3 must communicate between them securely" -- why? What difference does it make to the user what other apps are talking to that bridge app? "make sure that the bindings come from my API and not any malware?" -- why do you care? Why is it "malware" to talk to your bridge app? We don't need permissions to talk to external displays, Chromecasts, and the like. We don't need permissions to receive input from external keyboards, mice, and the like. Remember: permissions are there to inform the user about the communication, so why does the user care in this case?

Comment: @CommonsWare - the *user* might want to **know or approve** what apps are trying to talk to the controller app.  That at least is distinct from the more philosophical question of the controller app's *developer* trying to restrict what apps are allowed to.

Comment: You could do some sort of token authentication over any instance-private IPC communication channel.  There are many choices as to what you use for tokens - they could be hardcoded, assigned by a server both apps contact, entered by the user, made up randomly and accepted by the user...  A range of comparable examples could include API keys, digital certificate hierarchies, bluetooth pairing pins, etc

Comment: Thanks you for your comments both of you, they led me onto the right track, i.e. reconsidering what is a "malware" in this context. A combination of authentication by package name + limit of simultaneous clients does avoid a malware behaviour such as adding charge to the service by infinitely binding to it. I dropped the custom permission, even if then I lose the ability to show the user what the app he's about to install does.